# Is it possible to have malware in Google Chrome?

Tags: malware

Some pop-up ads have been appearing. Chrome blocks them, but it's annoying anyway. Some websites (like Google Reader) seems to not work well due to this.

I suspect this is due to a malware in Chrome for a couple of reasons: It is only in Chrome (not in Firefox), and it seems to have been syncronized through my other PC (with some delay).

I know it's pretty unlikely to have a malware or virus in Ubuntu but, I know too that Chrome uses Sandboxing. So... is it possible to have a malware "sheltering" in Chrome? If yes, how can I remove it.

Comment: Could you please list all Chrome extensions you have enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Sandboxing in Chrome is not yet fully implemented under Linux, however to get a malware is rare by every means. In case you are worried, you can always enable apparmor profiles for Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of your installed extensions. Delete any extensions you aren't sure about.

Try the [AdBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom?hl=nl) extension too.

Comment: Conversely, it could be because they *do* have an ad-blocker installed in Firefox but not in Chrome.